# Why the Golden calf was a calf and not a bull?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, animals, parashat-ki-tisa, golden-calf-egel

1. If I recall correctly, the sources say the idol was created grown up and fully functioning.
2. Even if it was still in infant stages, [Bava Kamma 65b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.65b.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

   > אמר רבא שור בן יומו קרוי שור
3. (*DonielF*) according to [Rashi (Shemos 32:4)](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.32.4?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Exodus.32.4&lang2=bi) they took Michah's golden plaque that said עלי שור on it and threw it into the fire, so a שור must come out.

I wonder why the idol is called everywhere "עגל" - calf and not a grown-up "שור" - bull?

Comment: I heard there was not enough gold to do more because the people in charge were stealing. Unlike Moshe Rabbenu later who gave a perfect account of all donations

Comment: And please remember to translate for the sake of non-Hebrew readers

Comment: Particularly according to Rashi to Shemos 32:4 that Michah took a golden plaque that said עלי שור on it and threw it into the fire, why did an עגל come out and not a שור?

Comment: I don’t think #2 is really a question. Even though an עגל is treated like a שור in regards to נזיקין, they’re still two different things. The passuk is being precise - they didn’t just make any שור, they specifically made an עגל.

Comment: 1. I added this fact to the Q 2. we all know it's called and עגל so your 2nd clarification adds nothing. 3. Specifically? please explain.

Comment: @Al (You forgot to ping.) You say an עגל is a שור and therefore even if it was an עגל it should be called a שור. My point is that they're still two separate things, even if in certain Halachic contexts they're the same; the Torah calls it an עגל because it was, in fact, an עגל.

Comment: What do you think the idol was, a calf or a grown bull? If it was a calf, then I don’t understand what your question is asking: it’s called a calf because it was a calf. If it was fully grown, then I think you need to source that in order to have a basis for your question.

Comment: @JoelK Wait for a second and think - would people follow a cute baby-idol with a baby face? 2. see #3 3. They asked for Moses' replacement - would a baby bull suffice?

Comment: @AlBerko You didn’t ask why they specifically made a calf. You asked why the calf isn’t referred to as a bull.

Comment: @doodle ok, help me to fine tune the question. The problem is apparent I think.

Answer (score 2):

In [Tehillim 106:19-20](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.106.19-20?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it does in fact  refer to the golden calf as both an *eigel* (calf) and a *shor* (bull):

> יעשו **עגל** בחרב וישתחוו למסכה. וימירו את כבודם בתבנית **שור** אכל

Though every *eigel* could be defined as a *shor* as quoted in Bava Kama 65b, A fully grown *shor* cannot be defined as an *eigel* bwhich is specifically reffering to its young state (example "mankind" includes chidren but children dos not include grown men).